# What would a world around 1930-1940 look like, that had gas instead of crude oil as main energysource for transportation?

Tags: technological-development

I refer to cars or the like, airtransportation, heating, ilumination.

Comment: You mean that crude oil doesn't exist (and never did?) in this world? And gas is available in large amounts? Or that oil suddenly disappeared? Because the world of "1930-1940" depends heavily on what happened before then and removing oil has a pretty big impact and would change a lot of events.

Comment: i believe that this depends where the gas deposits are. the consequences is merely political. gasoline/diesel are more effective as fuels than gaseous fuels. For example a gas conversion of a diesel engine has less than 50% the original power as diesel engine. This is due to the necessary derating of the engine due to lower capacity of the fuel to cool the engine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with natural gas is while it is a good source of energy, it is a gas so the energy density is quite low, and compressing or liquifying it makes it much more difficult and dangerous to handle. For most civilian uses, people will avoid this, and for industrial use, stationary engines and furnaces fuelled from a pipeline will do.

Assuming that in this scenario there never was any crude oil (as a commenter notes, oil was important as far back as the late 1800's), then some technologies like coal will still be in wide use as transportation fuel for things like ships and railroads, due to the high energy density and ease of use.

On a larger scale, since portable energy is scarce, cars, trucks and airplanes will also be quite rare. Airships have less of an issue, so some forms of flight will still be possible, just expensive and restricted to governments, military forces and the very wealthy. Battery powered electric cars and trucks will be in limited use for two reasons:

1. The electrical grid cannot handle vast fleets of cars (in our history, it was much quicker and easier to set up a gas station than to build new power lines, so electric cars eventually faded from use in the 1920's). Unless there is a very major push to build giant coal and gas fired power plants and a very robust grid, electric vehicles will not have the infrastructure needed. (This is true even today)
2. Batteries have very low energy density as well. A typical car battery has less energy stored within than a ham sandwich. The battery industry still does not have any way even today to bring battery energy density close to that of hydrocarbon fuels, which is the real reason electrical cars are a boutique item.

In terms of the history, this has very interesting implications. The mass Fascist movements in Europe might talk big, but unless they have huge armies of marching soldiers and lots of horse drawn transport, they are not going anywhere. OF course the democracies will have similar issues. The British Empire still controls the waves with fleets of coal powered battleships, and the French Republic (and indeed everyone) can shuttle troops rapidly from place to place within their own borders using trains, but once you cross the frontier you are on your own (anyone with any sense has a plan to demolish the railways in front of advancing armies.

Since everyone is afraid of replaying WWI, all military forces are focused on how to defend and avoid attrition. There might be a lot of sabre rattling, but actual armed clashes *may* be limited in scale and scope. The Russian revolution might also be much more limited in scope, since without access to compact, high density energy, industrializing and modernizing the USSR will be far slower. Russia will be a backwater and gradually falling farther behind, rather than a rapidly modernizing "vanguard" nation capable of attracting admirers and converts throughout the West.

Comment: This answer deserves many more up votes. This question makes me wonder how a world could have coal and not oil, considering they are both made under similar processes.